# Python sort a list of dictionaries

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionaries like this:

```
list = [

        {'name': 'title1', 'description': 'text1'},
        {'name': '[test] title2', 'description': 'text2'},
        {'name': 'title3', 'description': 'text3'},
        {'name': '[test] title4', 'description': 'text4'}
]
```

I need to exclude all dictionaries when a key 'name' has the word '[test]' and then sort by value 'name'.
How can I do this? Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: Please don't use Python reserved words as a variable name

Comment: Max V, yes I know, it`s just for example.

Answer (score 2):

Using a list comprehension:

```
sorted((element for element in list if element['name'] != 'test'), key=lambda element: element.get('name'))
```

Comment: This can be slow because the list comprehension builds an entire list first. filter does the same thing anyway (but lazy). Your idea does work with generator comprehensions though, that would look like this: sorted((element for element in list if element['name'] != 'test'), key=lambda element: element['name'])

(notice the parentheses instead of the square brackets)
(yes I know my own original solution also built a list. Thanks for Jacinator for noticing that :)

Comment: This also does *not* work because element["name"] will throw a KeyError when it does not exist. You will need to use the "in" operator. If it had worked I'd prefer "== None" instead.

Comment: @jonathan Instead of using "in" you should rather use ".get" on a dictionary. You should not check "== None", it should be "is None". List comprehensions and generator expressions are peferred over filter and map, you can find Guido talking about it and reduce being moved from default function to functools is an example of this.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this with a couple of list operations:

```py
result = sorted(
    # filter the list on items that have name
    filter(lambda i: "name" in i and "test" not in i["name"], list),

    # sort on this name
    key=lambda i: i['name']
)
```

Comment: Really you don't even have to wrap `filter` with `list` since `sorted` accepts a `filter` object.

Comment: cool, I did not know that. Decided to include it because then it would work regardless.  Didn't test the code I wrote (who the hell needs testing anyway duh /s) But good to know. Will edit

Comment: Jonathan, I used your advice and it helped me.